# How to fetch an object in Moogose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm trying to learn Mongoose and I'm trying to make a simple project. However, I can't understand how to do this.

I have a Schema like this (below) and I want to try to fetch results in this way...

**Example**: I want to get `roleID` where `gameID` is `111`

How can do it?

[image]

I tried to search solution on google but I still don't understand how to make it without create object for any game I put in array

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you, you need something like this

```
aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: '$games'
    },
    {
      $match: {
        'games.gameId': "111"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$games.gameId',
        roles: {
          $addToSet: '$games.roleId'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```